# Duplicated Field Not Sending In Email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

I'm creating a form that allows the user to duplicate a field for submitting numerous items.  I want the user to be able to duplicate the last 2 fields (quantity and item), which I've done via the script here.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Dynamic-Form-Field-Generator-DuplicateElement.html

[Form Screenshot][1]

For the fields that would be duplicated I included an array in the elements name since it apparently uses the :

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
                        <label class="control-label" for="quantity">Quantity</label>         
                          <input  class="form-control input-md" id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity[]" maxlength="2" size="2" required>
                        <label class="control-label" for="item">Item</label>
                          <input  class="form-control input-md" id="item" type="text" placeholder="Item Name" name="item[]" maxlength="100" size="68" required>
                    </div>
```

Once submitted the values are passed to a php file where I declared the array as:

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity']; // required
$item = $_POST['item']; // required
```

And attempted to include the array in the email message with:

```
$email_message .= "Quantity: ".[$quantity]."\n";
$email_message .= "Item: ".[$item]."\n";
```

However when I receive the email I only get "Array" as the fields value instead of the user entered text:

Quantity: Array

Item: Array

How can I get the email to include the various values from the duplicated fields?

Comment: You need to parse each array or loop through each array.

Answer (score 0):

As Jay said, you cannot echo an array. Here's an example of how you could generate your "Quantity" to send.

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$quantity_val = "";
if( is_array( $quantity ) && count( $quantity ) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $quantity as $q ) {
        $quantity_val .= "{$q}\n";
    }
}


$email_message .= "Quantity: {$quantity}";
```